# Laravel perform route action on select dropdown onchange, create specific URL

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I've got Dropdown select with the list with future 12 months:

```
<select name="month" id="specificMonth">
    @foreach(Carbon\CarbonPeriod::create(now()->startOfMonth(), '1 month', now()->addMonths(11)->startOfMonth()) as $date)
        <option value="{{ $date }}">
               {{ $date->format('F Y') }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

If the option in dropdown changes, I want to perform route action like:

```
 $('#specificMonth').change(function(){
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            alert(data);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                URL: "{{ route('calendar.specificMonth', 'date') }}",
                data: data,
                success: function () {
                    console.log("works");
                }
            });
       });
```

So I need to get the selected month in Controller and return view with specific month.
How I can do that?

When I "alerts" data it shows it correctly.

URL in my case should look like:

```
/calendar/{date}
```

Or something like that. For now my route for that looks like:

```
Route::post(
    '/calendar/{date}',
    [CalendarController::class, 'specificMonth']
)->name('calendar.specificMonth');
```

But performing an action in view gives me an error "POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/calendar 405 (Method Not Allowed)".

This should be POST or GET method? How to create custom URL in that case?

Updated, Method from Controller in which I want to dump data only:

```
public function specificMonth(Request $request, $date)
    {
        dd($request);
    }
```

Comment: what did you try so far? How does your controller look like

Comment: I only want to get it in controller and dump only for now.  I'll update only how my method look like in Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dump data while using ajax. You can use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::debug($request)` in the controller. Then the request will be shown in the storage/logs/logfielname.log.

Comment: But I can't even perform "form" submitting or something. I can't even pass data from select dropdown to Controller.

Comment: Try changinh the dd line to Log debug and check your result

Comment: Even if I got blank method in controller I got error 405.

Comment: is the route is a part of a route group with restrictions?

Comment: No, any restrictions there.